# How to notify OSX for an external file change

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, notifications

I found a way to refresh the finder when a file is externally changed using:

`[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] noteFileSystemChanged: path];`

But it looks like this does not notify the file system or any other apps about the change. What I'm trying to do is somehow broadcast a notification to every app using the file, or tell the OSX itself (and then the OSX to notify the apps) that it has changed.

I also tried using:

`[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification object: nil];`

But it does not work (also this notification is deprecated). And I don't know if other apps actually use this kind of notification system (for example I think VS Code is using it).

If there is a solution in c++ will be better, but objective c++ is also okay.